# Read works just one time

Tags: c

I'm trying to set up a TCP server, but the program does nothing the second time it passes through a read. I'll post some code in order to be clear : 
This is the client code

```
        while(menu1)
       {
        menu2=menu3=menu4=menu5=true;
        for (int i=0;i<499;i++)
            msg1[i]='\0';
        bzero(msg1,500);       
        printf("main menu\n");fflush(stdout);
        if (read(sd,msg1,sizeof(msg1))<=0)
        {  
            perror("Eroare la citire in meniu1 ");
            return errno;
        }
        printf("gets here\n");fflush(stdout);
        ...
```

This is the server code :

```
            while(menu1)//main menu
          {
            menu2=menu3=menu4=menu5=true;
            printf("beginning\n");fflush(stdout);
              if (write(client,msg1,sizeof(msg1))<=0)
              {
                perror("Eroare la scriere in meniu1 ");
                return errno;
              }
              printf("gets here too\n");fflush(stdout);
            ...
```

The first time it passes just fine, but the second time the client would just freeze after it prints "main menu". Afterwards it should've printed the "gets here" part but no, it just stays, like it is waiting for something. In server everything works fine, so i'm guessing the problem comes from the client from read. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does bzero do? Are you checking if your descriptor is valid after your first read/write , are you sure msg1 and size of msg1 are both the same in server and client?

Comment: If the client blocks in `read()`, then that would normally mean that the connection remains open but no more data are available to read.  If furthermore it blocks *indefinitely*, then the most likely conclusion is that the server only sends one message -- maybe it's awaiting a response from the client?  You have not presented the code we would need to consider to evaluate those possibilities.

Comment: Yeah....in the server, you are writing the whole buffer?  That buffer array is entirely filled with useful data, (I doubt it somehow)?  The bzero call and the loop to preload the buffer with NULs is cargo-cult cycle wastage - the read() return value tells you where to insert a terminating NUL, (assuming you need one).

Comment: Please post a [mcve] for the server and for the client so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.